# how to convert elastic query aggregate filter into nest query in .Net core

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, nest

How can I convert this Elastic search query into nest query. 
the query is given Bellow . 
GET  winlogbeat-6.6.0*/_search?size=0

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "success ": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "event_id": 4624 
        }
      }

    },
    "failed": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "event_id": 4625 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The desired out Output in Kibana is as follow

```
    {
      "took" : 13120,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 37,
        "successful" : 37,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : 299924794,
        "max_score" : 0.0,
        "hits" : [ ]
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "failed" : {
          "doc_count" : 351643
        },
        "success " : {
          "doc_count" : 40375274
        }
      }
    }
```

this is my code and i need to convert it NEST to get the desired result . 
Thanks

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: var queryWinlogbeat_6_6_0 = _elasticClient.Search<winlogbeat_6_6_0>(q => q
                       .Index("winlogbeat-6.6.0*")
                       .Size(0)
                       .Aggregations(a => a
                                  .Filter("Success", fa => fa
                                    .Filter(f => f.Term(o => o.event_id, 4624))
                                  )
                                )

                       );

This code return me correct record for "success" bucket but  how to another filter for "failed" bucked

Comment: @NisarAhmad you can edit a question to add additional detail, like what you have tried so far. This would also allow you to format it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to add another case by calling `.Filter(..)` on aggregations descriptor

```
var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Filter("success", success => success
            .Filter(filter => filter
                .Term(t => t.Field(f => f.EventId).Value(4624))))
        .Filter("failed", failed => failed
            .Filter(filter => filter
                .Term(t => t.Field(f => f.EventId).Value(4625))))));

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.